# Django Heroku /GET Favicon.Ico when running heroku logs --tail

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

My Heroku build is complete, but the application is not booting for some reason.

When I run `heroku logs --tail`,

```
2023-09-04T13:32:07.484629+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=journallove-e9a7a6e26520.herokuapp.com request_id=3515dc4d-fb0c-4ccb-bbdc-cb81a1ae5a31 fwd="130.58.166.192" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-09-04T13:32:07.768182+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=journallove-e9a7a6e26520.herokuapp.com request_id=8c703a21-5109-4f0a-af7a-22c0e2687c8a fwd="130.58.166.192" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-09-04T13:32:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-09-04T13:32:35.613845+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=journallove-e9a7a6e26520.herokuapp.com request_id=6c9caf84-4fb9-4a08-96ea-ee41bae09184 fwd="130.58.166.192" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-09-04T13:32:35.808771+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=journallove-e9a7a6e26520.herokuapp.com request_id=cd6e61e2-ee17-4f5e-abb4-c2ca33636d17 fwd="130.58.166.192" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-09-04T13:32:45.705631+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=journallove-e9a7a6e26520.herokuapp.com request_id=5d813e56-e116-4432-86f5-1ba43ba9227b fwd="130.58.166.192" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-09-04T13:32:45.899516+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=journallove-e9a7a6e26520.herokuapp.com request_id=14f662de-7547-40d0-bee9-522e847922c4 fwd="130.58.166.192" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

these are the issues that pop up.

This is my Procfile

```
web gunicorn journallove.wsgi:application --log-file -
```

and req.txt.

```
asgiref==3.6.0
blind==0.0.1
blinker==1.6.2
certifi==2023.5.7
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
click==8.1.3
cloudpickle==2.2.1
Cython==0.29.35
distlib==0.3.6
dj-database-url==2.1.0
Django==4.2.1
entrypoints==0.4
filelock==3.12.2
Flask==2.3.2
gitdb==4.0.10
GitPython==3.1.31
greenlet==2.0.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
idna==3.4
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
joblib==1.3.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
mysql-connector-python==8.0.33
mysqlclient==2.1.1
nltk==3.8.1
numpy==1.24.3
package-json==0.0.0
pandas==2.0.1
platformdirs==3.8.1
protobuf==3.20.3
psycopg2-binary==2.9.7
PyMySQL==1.0.3
pytz==2023.3
PyYAML==6.0
querystring-parser==1.2.4
regex==2023.6.3
requests==2.31.0
six==1.16.0
smmap==5.0.0
SQLAlchemy==2.0.15
sqlparse==0.4.4
templates==0.0.5
tqdm==4.65.0
typing_extensions==4.6.2
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==2.0.2
views-py==2.0.0
virtualenv==20.23.1
Werkzeug==2.3.4`
```

I tried to move the Procfile to the root directory because I saw that somebody suggested that. It did not work.

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this?

Answer (score 0):

You're focusing on the wrong thing. The Favicon errors aren't the problem here.

Your `Procfile` is malformed. Yes, it needs to be in the root directory, but it's also missing a colon:

```
web: gunicorn journallove.wsgi:application --log-file -
```

The [format of a `Procfile` is](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-format)

```
<process type>: <command>
```

and you want to declare a process type of `web` and a command of `gunicorn ...`.

---

Side note, you mention a file called `req.txt`. I suspect you're just trying to save typing, but that file must be called `requirements.txt` *exactly* if you expect Heroku to use it.